# find row that has the most matching values compared to other row in my data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Person A, Value 1, Value 2, Value 3, Value 4
Person B, Value 1, Value 2, Value 3, Value 4
```

Now I would like to compare single rows of this dataset against the whole set with the criteria to show the row that has the most matching Values compared to the single row Im looking at.

For example. I have a new entry Person C. I want to be able to show (in an analysis tab) the other people that have the most common values with that person from the dataset.

Comment: You could use `=COUNTIF(Range, Criteria1)+COUNTIF(Range, Criteria2)...` then filter for the highest number count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how is your data stored, but I made up a sample emulating what you said about how your data looks like. I hope you can adapt this to your needs.

I made this:

[image]

Left dataset would be your data with values, and right dataset would be your analysis. The formula I used to get this is:

```
=IF(J$1=$I2;"x";COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B" & MATCH(J$1;$A:$A;0) &":E"& MATCH(J$1;$A:$A;0));INDEX($B:$B;MATCH($I2;$A:$A;0)))+COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B" & MATCH(J$1;$A:$A;0) &":E"& MATCH(J$1;$A:$A;0));INDEX($C:$C;MATCH($I2;$A:$A;0)))+COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B" & MATCH(J$1;$A:$A;0) &":E"& MATCH(J$1;$A:$A;0));INDEX($D:$D;MATCH($I2;$A:$A;0)))+COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B" & MATCH(J$1;$A:$A;0) &":E"& MATCH(J$1;$A:$A;0));INDEX($E:$E;MATCH($I2;$A:$A;0))))
```

It may looks complex but it's easier than it looks. This formula is composed of several parts:

1. `INDEX($B:$B;MATCH($I2;$A:$A;0)))` will return the criteria of the person in same row, but column B.
2. `INDIRECT("B" & MATCH(J$1;$A:$A;0) &":E"& MATCH(J$1;$A:$A;0));` will return as range the range of values from left dataset of the person you are matching up (header data) in the right dataset.
3. We can combine both of above with a COUNTIF to count how many times the value of the person in same row appears in the range of values of person in headers. We combine them as `COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B" & MATCH(J$1;$A:$A;0) &":E"& MATCH(J$1;$A:$A;0));INDEX($B:$B;MATCH($I2;$A:$A;0)))`.
4. The above formula is just for 1 criteria, so you need to add extra COUNIF for each criteria you got (in this exampple, it would be 4 criterias, so 4 COUNIF).
5. The initial `IF` is useful just to show an `X` if the Intersection you are analyzing is same person in row and header.
6. After that, you can use conditional formatting in each row of right dataset to show max value.

The good thing of this method is that values on left dataset don't need to be in same column to be counted properly. If you look at image, Person 1 and PErson 2 matches perfectly, even if values are not in same order, because formula counts in whole range all the time.

I've uploaded a sample to my Gdrive in case you want to download and check the formulas properly (could be i made a translation error typing, because my excel is in spanish).

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kPAARG8yAkXok7HxYkYswDiCAT37mmEz

With VBA probably you could do a macro that just shows the row number of person with better matches, but make sure you check ALL data, because maybe it could be that a person matches with 2 or more people, and all of them got max values. With this design, you could see that because both cell would be colored in green.

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for that indepth answer! I will try to implement it right now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, Total As Long, j As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        arr = .Range("A2:E" & LastRow)

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

            For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

                If arr(i, 1) <> arr(j, 1) Then

                    'Check Value 1
                    If arr(i, 2) = arr(j, 2) Then
                        Total = Total + 1
                    End If

                    'Check Value 2
                    If arr(i, 3) = arr(j, 3) Then
                        Total = Total + 1
                    End If

                    'Check Value 3
                    If arr(i, 4) = arr(j, 4) Then
                        Total = Total + 1
                    End If

                    'Check Value 4
                    If arr(i, 5) = arr(j, 5) Then
                        Total = Total + 1
                    End If

                    If .Range("G" & i + 1).Value = "" Then
                        .Range("G" & i + 1).Value = arr(j, 1)
                        .Range("H" & i + 1).Value = Total / 4
                    ElseIf Total / 4 > .Range("H" & i + 1).Value Then
                        .Range("G" & i + 1).Value = arr(j, 1)
                        .Range("H" & i + 1).Value = Total / 4
                    End If

                    Total = 0

                End If

            Next j

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]